# No fieldset padding top in IE8

Tags: html, css, forms, padding, fieldset

Sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
fieldset {padding: 50px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Form</legend>
  <p>
  <label for="name">Name </label><input id="name" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="email">Email </label><input id="email" type="text">
  </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in all major browsers, but there's no padding top in IE8. Any cross-browser solution?

Comment: No, it doesn't. To show the problem better, I just increased the padding to 50px.

Comment: I have run your example in every browser i have installed, including ie7/8/9, firefox, chrome and opera and the padding works as expected, for any given value.

Comment: Here's what I see in IE8:[Sample form](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/screenshot3.jpg). Please compare the top and bottom padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to a bug in older versions of IE, possibly caused by some confusion around the `legend` element (which is nested inside `fieldset` but rendered in a special way), so that the padding gets misplaced above the form. I can more or less reproduce the issue on IE 9 in Quirks Mode and in IE 8 and IE 7 emulation mode.

As a workaround, do not set top padding on the `fieldset` element. Instead, set a top margin on the first normal element inside it (not counting the `legend` element).

Comment: Yes. You can see the padding above the fieldset in this jsfiddle in old ie:
http://jsfiddle.net/XSrK4/

Compare that to this fieldset with no label, which does not have this bug: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XSrK4/1/

So the other solution you could do is omit the legend tag and the padding will work correctly.

Comment: @3dgoo: But I _need_ the legend.

Comment: Then Jukka's answer explains a way to do this.